# Using variables in SSIS Data flow task and Execute process task

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis, script-task, dataflowtask

I created a package and added a data flow task that reads the data from database and creates a flat out xml file. It then stores the file in the path I have given and the execute process task uploads it to a remote server. Below is how the structure looks like:

[image]

The data flow task is something like this:

[image]

The execute process task is like below:

[image]

So they all work fine right now as I have absolute directory paths for data flow flat out file process and in the Execute process task.

But what I am trying to do is to remove the absolute path and use relative path to the root folder of my package.dtsx file instead for all the executable, storing the flat out xml file etc.

So after researching online these two links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27630845/how-to-set-variables-in-an-ssis-package) and [here](http://www.select-sql.com/mssql/how-to-use-a-variable-inside-sql-in-ssis-data-flow-tasks.html) proved very helpful. I created a variable and the script task as shown in the first screenshot above. The details of the script task are:

[image]

Below is the main function of script task:

[image]

After adding the variable I am able to see in the package properties that the variable PackagePath is assigned some value like this `\Package\task-name`:

[image]

But I am not sure what path is that and how to get to the root directory or assign the root directory path to the variable.

I am new to SSIS so not sure if I am doing it wrong or missing something. Been struggling last couple days to figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try setting `Delay Validation` property to `True`, check my answer for more details

Answer (score 2):

To use variables in Execute Process Task, you have to use expressions, open the `Execute Process Task` editor, Go To expressions Tab and write your expressions.

You can refer to  this article for a detailed example:

- [SSIS - How To Unzip .Zip Files In SSIS [ How To Use Execute Process Task In SSIS ]](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-unzip-zip-files-in-ssis-how.html)

Also you can read more about `Execute Process Task` and writing expressions at:

- [Execute Process Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/execute-process-task)

---

*Note: Right click on your Execute Process Task and select Properties. In the properties window, you will have a `DelayValidation` option that is currently set to `False` Flip that to `True`.*