# How to use the date from a FileName and use this date in an expression - SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssis

I am quite a beginner with SSIS packages so bear with me. What I am trying to do:

I have daily files in the format of yyyy-mm-dd_filename_bla_bla.tsv
The date of the file need to be added in the table were I am trying to import it. Currently I am doing this manually with a derived coloumn with the expression: (DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)"yyyy-mm-dd"

Is there a possibility to automatically take the file name and only take the date part to import it into the table.

The things I find on the internet is getting the date into the file name, but this is exactly the opposite.

I hope I provided enough information, and anyone can help me out with this problem.

thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to concat present date to  ur file name...???

Comment: the date from the file.

Comment: For the current file name, do you have it in an SSIS Variable as just `                yyyy-mm-dd_filename_bla_bla.tsv` or does it have the fully qualified path `C:\ssisdata\Source\Input\yyyy-mm-dd_filename_bla_bla.tsv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file name then keep that file name in a variable
example let  file name be : **01/02/2015_kjh.bgd**

then by using derived column use string functions as **left(@variable,10)**

10-> length of date

then map it to your oledb destination

Comment: did you get what am I saying

Comment: I did get what you are saying but this is static no? When using the same package for another file, with different date it wouldn't update? What I would like to get is to make it dynamic. example file: 2015-02-25.company.prod.sisense_data.tsv where date is changing.

Comment: yes you have to use foreachloop container to get the names of the files in a specific folder and u will assign the name to the variable in container only

Comment: Right now I am using this expression: (DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)LEFT(@[User::CurrentFile],10) which does not seem to be actually storing anything to the database. (DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)"2015-02-16" does work however. What is it what I am doing wrong? The variable currrentfile does seem to be working though.

Comment: are u able to convert it to date if so then map it to destination vial oledb dest

Answer (score 0):

To update/insert into a table you can use the SSIS SQL Exec task and pass in the variable value (which you know how to get) into the update/insert statement as a parameter. Its not hard just be careful on your settings of parameter names 0.

Here is a detailed description on how to do exactly what you are asking once you have a parameter set up:
[How to pass variable as a parameter in Execute SQL Task SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610491/how-to-pass-variable-as-a-parameter-in-execute-sql-task-ssis)