# How to log the output of SSIS Execute SQL Task

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am new to SSIS.

I created SSIS Package using Execute SQL Task. I called a Stored Procedure.
My stored procedure prints few messages like 
'Insert Started'
'Update Started'
'Update Completed'
but it does not return any result set.

How do I write the output of stored procedure to a log file in SSIS.

Kindly help me out I am struggling for the past two days.

I tried using DTExec like this

DTExec /f "C:\Users\Karthick\Desktop\SSIS\Package.dtsx">MyOutput.txt

But it prints only Execute SQL Task values not the Stored procedure print statements.

Comment: Please tell me How do I write the output of stored procedure to a log file in SSIS

Answer (score 3):

SSIS is the kind of product that if you right click it enough it will eventually do something. But seriously folks, it reminds me of VB6 having a bad day…

This sounds like a simple thing to do but it requires a lot of right clicking and squirreling away little bits of code here and there. Here are the steps:

1. Declare one or more [output parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-a-stored-procedure-with-output-parameters) in your stored procedure (SPROC) to contain your status messages
2. In SSIS, [modify your call](http://www.julian-kuiters.id.au/article.php/ssis-execute-sql-task-output-parameters) to the SPROC to contain SSIS question mark "wildcards" (or whatever they call them)
3. Add a [variable](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-introducing-variables/) to SSIS
4. [Map SPROC output parameter(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610491/how-to-pass-variable-as-a-parameter-in-execute-sql-task-ssis) to SSIS variable
5. Set up the [logging provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/performance/integration-services-ssis-logging) in SSIS
6. Enable an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-ssis-event-handlers) to trigger writing your status messages to the log
7. Create another task is SSIS to actually write the data to the log. I recommend using SQL but up to you

If you read the links above you will get the idea. Read on for a few details and editorial comments.

The place to start is with your SPROC by declaring one or more output parameters and setting them with your status messages.

```
SET @my_status = 'Insert Started'
```

Maybe you want to concatenate all your messages into one output parameter, or have multiple ones. Up to you.

Now, right click your SSIS Control Flow canvas and add a variable. Rinse and repeat if you have more SPROC output parameters.

Right click your SQL Task and edit your SQL call to look something like this:

```
EXEC myStoredProcedure ? OUTPUT
```

If you have input parameters those need to be accounted for here.  The ? Is important as it represents a zero based numbered parameter that you have to map in order for SSIS to actually do anything with your status message.  The design is reminiscent of Wordstar mail merges from back in the stone age of personal computing.

Go to Parameter mapping. Click Add and look for your variable. It will be something ugly like

```
User::my_status
```

If we all thought Parameter Name was the parameter name we would all be wrong. In this example you would put 0 (zero) here since this is obviously the zero-eth parameter in your SPROC.

OK, now you have set up a variable that you can log. But you're not done yet. You have to set up another Execute SQL Task to actually log this.  I am not going to walk you through this dear reader but hopefully [Aalam Rangi](http://www.sqlerudition.com/how-to-log-ssis-variable-values-during-execution-in-the-event-log/)'s excellent article is still there to give you everything you need to do this. In a nutshell you must a) set up the SSIS logging provider, b)Enable an event that will trigger writing your data to the log, c) write a SQL insert statement with a bunch more question marks in it that will actually write your data to the standard SQL table you want to log to. If you want to log to a file, this article will still be helpful. Here is the insert code which works perfectly for SSIS and Visual Studio 2015. Thanks Aalam!

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[sysssislog]
([event]
,[computer]
,[operator]
,[ source]
,[sourceid]
,[executionid]
,[starttime]
,[endtime]
,[datacode]
,[databytes]
,[message])
VALUES
('*SSIS-OnVariableValueChanged' -- Custom event name
,? -- param 0
,? -- param 1
,? -- param 2
,? -- param 3
,? -- param 4
,? -- param 5
,? -- param 6
,0 -- Zero
,'' -- Blank string
,?) -- param 7
```

Happy right clicking!

Answer (score 1):

You can approach in this way,

- Log SSIS in a SQL Table
- Log your stored procedure in a table
- Create a view for see for example together the logtable
- and print this view with the SSIS in a file

Comment: Is there any simplest way to achieve this

Comment: My question is how to log the stored procedure print statements to log file

Comment: i understand your question, but there is no way to do it directly. you must do a trick like this

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can not catch the stored procedure print messages through `Execute SQL Task`. To do that you need to use either `Script Task` or `Script Component`. Inside the script you can invoke your stored procedure and use the Event Handler `InfoMessage` to catch the messages from stored procedure.

Sample code below -

```
        public event SqlInfoMessageEventHandler InfoMessage;
        void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(<your log file path>))
                 {
                  writer.Write(e.Message);
                 }
        }

        public void Main()
        {
         using (var conn = new SqlConnection(<your connection manager>))
         using (var command = new SqlCommand(<your sp name>, conn)
             {
             CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
             })
         try
            {
             {
              ((SqlConnection)conn).InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(myConnection_InfoMessage);
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
            }
         catch
            {
              throw;
            }
         finally
            {
              command.Dispose();
            }

         Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
         }
```