# SSIS passing paramater in SQL command with ODBC

Tags: variables, ssis, sqlcommand, expressionbuilder

I am trying to run a variable in an expression builder SQL command for OBDC.

The expression looks like this below

```
"SELECT Date(Curdate())                   AS 'Load Date', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'TBR' 
                  AND Date(portdate) < Curdate() THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total Removes', 
            Min(CASE 
                         WHEN pomstatus = 'TBR' THEN portdate 
                         ELSE 'N/A' 
                       END) AS 'Oldest Removes', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'TBR' 
                  AND Date(portdate) < Curdate() 
                  AND Date(portdate) > Subdate(Curdate(),  @[User::Days] )THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total New Removes', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'TBR' 
                  AND acctype = 'b' 
                  AND Date(portdate) < Curdate() THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'SOHO Removes', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'C-U' 
                  AND Date(dd) < Curdate() THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total Confirmed U', 
            Min(CASE 
                         WHEN pomstatus = 'C-U' THEN dd 
                         ELSE 'N/A' 
                       END) AS 'Oldest Confirmed U', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'C-U' 
                  AND discoservice LIKE '%s%' 
                  AND Date(dd) < Curdate()THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total Confirmed Satellite', 
            Min(CASE 
                         WHEN pomstatus = 'C-U' 
                              AND discoservice LIKE '%s%' THEN dd 
                         ELSE 'N/A' 
                       END) AS 'Oldest Confirmed Satellite', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'C-U' 
                  AND Date(dd) < Curdate() 
                  AND Date(dd) > Subdate(Curdate(),   @[User::Days] ) THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total New Confirmed U', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'pwo' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total Pending WO', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'etbr' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total Escalated TBR', 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN pomstatus = 'wtnr' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END)                          AS 'Total Waiting TNR' 
FROM   POM.mainorders 
WHERE  acctype <> 'c';"
```

I get the below error:

**Error popup**

[image: Error popup]

I tested the same script but replaced the 2 variables with the number 2 and it was successful, so I know the script itself is working. It looks to me like the variable isn't passing properly.

As for how I am populating the variable, the variable gets populated form an execute SQL Task imaged below:

**Execute SQL task**

[image: Execute SQL task]

---

**Execute SQL Task**

[image: Execute SQL Task]

---

**Query Builder Result**

[image: Query Builder Result]

Comment: See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46739168/1507566

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable as a parameter in Execute SQL Task SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610491/how-to-pass-variable-as-a-parameter-in-execute-sql-task-ssis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't recognize the variable inside the string

try concatenating the string with this:

```
Subdate(Curdate(), "+ @[User::Days] + " )
```

Personally, I would create a stored procedure in the database and pass the two parameters, but not everyone has access to do that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how parameters work with the Execute SQL Task.

Either you use string concatenation as @KeithL suggests or properly map variables (@[User::Days]) to parameters (depends on your provider - either an ordinal based `?` marker or a named parameter `@myvalue`)

Since your provider indicates OLE DB, you will need to use a `?` as the placeholder and it then becomes a 0 based ordinal system. Click on Parameter Mapping and the name of the parameter is `0` and the Variable is `@[User::Days]`

See also Books OnLine - [Map Query Parameters to Variables in an Execute SQL Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140355(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I did try this but I couldnt get it working/couldnt understand it properly. KeithL suggestion worked but I will keep this in mind for future problems.