# SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR 0x80040E21 Invalid character value for cast specification

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am new to SSIS and just started experimenting. I am trying to figure out how to pass parameters from the ssis project to sql statement in the project. I have an sql script defined in an OLE DB data source with the access mode to the data source being an SQL command. In the where clause, I have where date between ? and ? and create two project level parameters, startdate and enddate, [image]

which i want to be read into the where clause at run-time. When I run the package I get this error

Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

Not sure where I am going wrong. Can someone please assist.

I am **NOT** using execute SQL Task, I have my script in ole db source connector [image]

And this is how I have my variable for the ? parameters

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable as a parameter in Execute SQL Task SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610491/how-to-pass-variable-as-a-parameter-in-execute-sql-task-ssis)

Comment: Try to execute the SQL statement by replacing the ? with the actual values. It looks like it tries to cast your parameter value to match the [date] column. 

Or your parameter isn't defined properly and tries to insert a blank which, for obvious reasons, can't be cast to a date. In that case, see @J Weezy's comment.

Comment: Show us how you have the parameters mapped in your Data Source.

Comment: I update the post for more clarity. When I hard code the date parameter as 'yyyymmdd' it works. This can be seen up the updated post.

Comment: Instead of using SQL command create a variable with your SQL and use Expression in the variable to build out the query with the dates in the expression then in the execute SQL use the Execute as Variable option instead.

Comment: @Brad is that this cannot be achieved using SQL command?

Comment: It should be able to, but sometimes it is easier to debug if you populate the variable (and easier to identify issues) because you can see what the full query looks like in the expression builder.  Also you can use a c# script task and a MessageBox in your code (or to some other way) to display the results of the variable on execution of the package debugging just before it executes (after the variables are populated).  So you can see the exact SQL text a bit easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The was partly due to casting issue with the date. In SSIS, in seems dates in the format yyyymmdd don't automatically convert to a date datatype like it does in t-sql as such it throws a "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" Hresult: 0x80040E21 Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

To fix this, I create two variables startdate and enddate and used expressions to convert my project level parameters `$Project::startdate` and `$Project::enddate` which were in yyyymmdd format to a date datatype like so `SUBSTRING(@[$Project::startdate],1,4) + "-" +
 SUBSTRING(@[$Project::startdate],5,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(@[$Project::startdate],7,2)`.

[image]

Then mapped by new variables to the parameters in my SQL script like so:

[image]