# SSIS Pass variable to Execute SQL Update

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a variable called 'Test123' - it is a string.

I then have an Execute SQL Task.  I have mapped the variable as a parameter - Direction = Input \ Data Type = String \ Parameter Name = 0 \ Size = 512

The actual SQL is thus:

```
 update [MyTable] set MyField = ? where MyField2 = 'xxx'
```

However, I keep receiving the error:

```
 "Incorrect syntax near '?'
```

Where am I going wrong?  I thought you use the question mark for parameters (that I've mapped to the variable)

Comment: I *assume* you are using the `Direct Input` option for your `SQLSourceType` property? The error suggests you aren't.

Comment: Also, i recommend leaving the `Parameter Size` value as `-1`.

Comment: What type of Connection Manager is being used by the Execute SQL Task?

Comment: Already Direct Input yes.  Tried Parameter Size as -1 to no avail.  Connection Type = ADO.NET

Comment: Ahh, there's the problem then. Why aren't you using an OLE DB connection?

Comment: Tab Alberman asked because ? works with OLEDB. I have often resorted to building my SQL statement in a variable, which I often find easier

Comment: See this answer in the duplicate:    https://stackoverflow.com/a/46739168/1507566

Comment: @TabAlleman - ah I see, thank you.